# How to resolve scala.MatchError when creating a Data Frame

Tags: scala, dataframe, rdd, case-class

I have text file which has complex structured row. I am using customer converter which converts the given string(line) to Pojo class(countryInfo). After converting, I am building DF. The POJO class has a field which is a List of Custome Type(GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows). I created a Struct which matches this GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows and trying to convert the existing Custom Type to the Struct but keep getting error.

StructType I created :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

  val PlayTimeWindow =
    StructType(
      StructField("startTime", DateType, true) ::
        StructField("endTime", DateType, true) :: Nil)


  val globalizedPlayTimeWindows =
    StructType(
                StructField( "countries", ArrayType(StringType, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "purchase", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "rental", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "free", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "download", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "advertisement", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "playTypeIds", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "benefitIds", MapType(StringType, ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true), true)  :: Nil)



  val schema =    StructType(
     StructField("id", StringType, true) ::
      StructField("jazzCount", IntegerType, true) ::
      StructField("rockCount", IntegerType, true) ::
      StructField("classicCount", IntegerType, true) ::
      StructField("nonclassicCount", IntegerType, true) ::
      StructField("musicType", StringType, true) ::
      StructField( "playType", ArrayType(globalizedPlayTimeWindows, true), true) :: Nil)
```

Data frame creation :

```
val mappingFile = sc.textFile("s3://input.....")

val inputData = mappingFile.map(x=> {
    val countryInfo = MappingUtils.getCountryInfo(x)

    val id = countryInfo.getId

    val musicType = if(countryInfo.getmusicType != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(countryInfo.getmusicType)) countryInfo.getmusicType else "UNKOWN_TYPE"


    val classicWestern = if (countryInfo.getClassic() != null && countryInfo.getClassic.size() > 0) true  else false

    var nonclassicCount : Int = 0
    var  classicCount : Int = 0

    if (classicWestern) {
      classicCount = 1
    } else {
      nonclassicCount = 1
    }


    val jazzrock = if (countryInfo.getmusicType() != null && countryInfo.getmusicType != "JAZZ") true  else false
    var jazzCount : Int = 0
    var  rockCount : Int = 0

    if (jazzrock) {
      jazzCount = 1
    } else {
      rockCount = 1
    }

    val playType = if(countryInfo.getPlayTimeWindows != null && countryInfo.getPlayTimeWindows.size > 0 ) { countryInfo.getPlayTimeWindows.asScala.toList } else null

  (id, jazzCount, rockCount, classicCount, nonclassicCount, musicType ,playType)
  }).map{case (id, jazzCount, rockCount, classicCount, nonclassicCount, musicType,playType) => Row(id, jazzCount, rockCount, classicCount, nonclassicCount, musicType,playType)
  }.persist(DISK_ONLY)

 val inputDataDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(inputData, schema)
```

inputDataDF.printSchema :

```
root 
|-- id: string (nullable = true) 
|-- jazzCount: integer (nullable = true) 
|-- rockCount: integer (nullable = true) 
|-- classicCount: integer (nullable = true) 
|-- nonclassicCount: integer (nullable = true) 
|-- musicType: string (nullable = true) 
|-- playType: array (nullable = true) 
| |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
| | |-- countries: array (nullable = true) 
| | | |-- element: string (containsNull = true) 
| | |-- purchase: array (nullable = true) 
| | | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
| | | | |-- startTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | | | |-- endTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | |-- rental: array (nullable = true) 
| | | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
| | | | |-- startTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | | | |-- endTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | |-- free: array (nullable = true) 
| | | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
| | | | |-- startTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | | | |-- endTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | |-- download: array (nullable = true) 
| | | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
| | | | |-- startTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | | | |-- endTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | |-- advertisement: array (nullable = true) 
| | | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
| | | | |-- startTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | | | |-- endTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | |-- playTypeIds: array (nullable = true) 
| | | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
| | | | |-- startTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | | | |-- endTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | |-- benefitIds: map (nullable = true) 
| | | |-- key: string 
| | | |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true) 
| | | | |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
| | | | | |-- startTime: date (nullable = true) 
| | | | | |-- endTime: date (nullable = true)
```

Struct's equivalent POJO :

```
@Data
public GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows(

    private final List<String> countries;

    private final List<PlayTimeWindow> purchase;

    private final List<PlayTimeWindow> rental;

    private final List<PlayTimeWindow> free;

    private final List<PlayTimeWindow> download;

    private final List<PlayTimeWindow> advertisement;

    private final List<PlayTimeWindow> preorderExclusive;

    private final Map<String, List<PlayTimeWindow>> playTypeIds;

}

@Data
public class PlayTimeWindow {

    private final Date startTime;

    private final Date endTime;
}
```

The error I am getting :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 12.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 12.0 (TID 393, ip-172-31-14-43.ec2.internal): scala.MatchError: GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows(countries=[US], purchase=null, rental=null, free=null, download=null, advertisement=null, preorderExclusive=null, playTypeIds=null) (of class com.model.global.GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:255) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter$$anonfun$toCatalystImpl$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:163) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244) at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:163) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:153) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:260) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401) at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492) at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312) at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157) at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Driver stacktrace: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418) at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799) at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588) at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1538) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1538) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2125) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1537) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1544) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1414) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1413) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2138) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1413) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1495) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:171) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:394) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:355) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:363) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:163) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:168) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:170) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:172) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:174) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:176) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:178) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:180) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:182) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:184) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:186) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:188) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:190) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:192) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:194) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:196) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:198) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:200) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:202) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:204) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:206) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:208) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:210) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:212) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:214) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:216) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:218) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:220) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:222) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:224) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:226) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:228) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:230) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:232) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:234) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:236) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:238) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:240) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:242) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:244) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:246) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:248) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:250) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:252) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:254) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:256) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:258) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:260) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:262) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:264) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:266) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:268) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:270) at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:272) at $iwC.<init>(<console>:274) at <init>(<console>:276) at .<init>(<console>:280) at .<clinit>(<console>) at .<init>(<console>:7) at .<clinit>(<console>) at $print(<console>) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065) at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346) at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840) at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871) at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819) at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:664) at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:629) at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:622) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:57) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:276) at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:170) at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:118) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also tried to do implicit toDF from inputData :

inputData.toDF.printSchema but getting error :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type com.model.global.GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows is not supported at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:718) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:667) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:693) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$schemaFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:691) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) at
```

Comment: It's hard to follow the types in your code - there are no explicit type annotations and the code for `countryInfo` is missing... Try calling `inputData.toDF().printSchema()` (after importing `sqlContext.implicits._`) to see the _actual_ schema that your code is creating, and look for the difference between that and your _expected_ schema.

Comment: I can see the schema with printSchema, I am getting this error when trying to do show()

Comment: The schema that you create yourself probably doesn't match the actual schema - I was suggesting that you DO NOT use your own schema but let Spark _infer_ it (which can be done using `toDF`) and then _compare_ the two schemas.

Comment: @TzachZohar Yeah Just tried like U advised (inputData.toDF().printSchema()) but I am getting : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type com.model.GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows is not supported at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:718) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30)

Comment: Right - so it worked - you've just found the root problem! as far as I know, Spark can only parse primitives, collections, and Scala `Product`s, which are basically _case classes_ and _tuples_. It can't parse just any arbitrary Java class. If `countryInfo.getPlayTimeWindows` returns a list of `GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows` - Spark won't be able to parse it into a Dataframe. Try converting your Java POJOs into Scala case classes maybe.

Comment: There is only one place I can see where you would get a MatchError. That's in the second anonymous function that you apply to your mappingFile. You write: { case(id,...) => Row(...) }. I would suggest adding a case _ => throw new Exception("...") just so that you can see why you are not matching the case as expected.

Comment: @TzachZohar Instead of using StructTypes ?

Comment: @Phasmid Yeah you are correct, it is due to what Zohar mentioned. Spark won't be able to parse it into a Dataframe due to Custom Type  - countryInfo.getPlayTimeWindows returns a list of GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows

Comment: @TzachZohar How about converting countryInfo.getPlayTimeWindows to json and match create a data frame with schema ?

Comment: No - not instead of using `StructType` - StructType is the _schema_, the problem is that your _data_, that contains objects of type `GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows` doesn't match that schema - if you convert each Java class you're using here in the data into a Scala case class (or another subclass of `scalaProduct`) Spark would be able to parse it.

Comment: @TzachZohar The java class is a dependency which I can not change. Is there any other option to achieve this ?

Comment: You don't have to change it, just create a matching version of the same model as a case class, and convert the Java instances into it. Alternatively use tuples of collections and primitives to model the data.

Comment: @TzachZohar  So I created 2 case class : case class PlayTimeWindowScala(startTime : java.util.Date, endTime : java.util.Date )   extends Serializable

case class GlobalizedPlayTimeWindowsScala (countries: List[String], purchase: List[PlayTimeWindowScala] ,rental: List[PlayTimeWindowScala],free: List[PlayTimeWindowScala],download: List[PlayTimeWindowScala], advertisement: List[PlayTimeWindowScala], preorderExclusive: List[PlayTimeWindowScala],playTypeIds: Map[String, List[PlayTimeWindowScala]]) extends Serializable
 which matches the java POJO.

Comment: @TzachZohar  Now I all I need to do is :   countryInfo.getPlayTimeWindows.asInstanceOf[GlobalizedPlayTimeWindowsScala]  ? Please correct me If I am wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - to cut the long discussion short, here's a working solution. Basically you had two separate issues here:

1. You expected Spark to be able to parse an arbitrary Java class into a DataFrame - that is not the case, Spark can only parse specific types, which are generally: Scala collections; Primitives; `java.sql.Date`; and any subclass of `scala.Product` - all case classes and tuples, for instance. So - as discussed in comments, the first thing to do is to convert your existing structure into such types.
2. Your `schema` didn't match your Java class either - there were a few differences:

   - Schema's `playType` was an *Array* of `GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows`, while your code created a *single* item and not an array
   - `globalizedPlayTimeWindows` schema contained `benefitIds` which doesn't exist in the Java class
   - `playTypeIds` schema was an *Array*, while the field with the same name in the Java class was a `Map`

So - I corrected all these (changed the schema to match the data, you can choose to fix these differently as long as they *match*) and completed the conversion of the Java classes into case classes:

```
// corrected schemas:
val PlayTimeWindow =
  StructType(
    StructField("startTime", DateType, true) ::
      StructField("endTime", DateType, true) :: Nil)

val globalizedPlayTimeWindows =
  StructType(
    StructField( "countries", ArrayType(StringType, true), true )  ::
      StructField( "purchase", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
      StructField( "rental", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
      StructField( "free", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
      StructField( "download", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
      StructField( "advertisement", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
      StructField( "preorderExclusive", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
      StructField( "playTypeIds", MapType(StringType, ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true), true )  ::
      Nil)

val schema =    StructType(
  StructField("id", StringType, true) ::
    StructField("jazzCount", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("rockCount", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("classicCount", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("nonclassicCount", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("musicType", StringType, true) ::
    StructField( "playType", globalizedPlayTimeWindows, true) :: Nil)

// note the use of java.sql.Date, java.util.Date not supported
case class PlayTimeWindowScala(startTime: java.sql.Date, endTime: java.sql.Date)

case class GlobalizedPlayTimeWindowsScala (countries: List[String],
                                           purchase: List[PlayTimeWindowScala],
                                           rental: List[PlayTimeWindowScala],
                                           free: List[PlayTimeWindowScala],
                                           download: List[PlayTimeWindowScala],
                                           advertisement: List[PlayTimeWindowScala],
                                           preorderExclusive: List[PlayTimeWindowScala],
                                           playTypeIds: Map[String, List[PlayTimeWindowScala]])

// some conversion methods:
def toSqlDate(jDate: java.util.Date): java.sql.Date = new java.sql.Date(jDate.getTime)

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def toScalaWindowList(l: java.util.List[PlayTimeWindow]): List[PlayTimeWindowScala] = {
  l.asScala.map(javaWindow => PlayTimeWindowScala(toSqlDate(javaWindow.startTime), toSqlDate(javaWindow.endTime))).toList
}

def toScalaGlobalizedWindows(javaObj: GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows): GlobalizedPlayTimeWindowsScala = {
  GlobalizedPlayTimeWindowsScala(
    javaObj.countries.asScala.toList,
    toScalaWindowList(javaObj.purchase),
    toScalaWindowList(javaObj.rental),
    toScalaWindowList(javaObj.free),
    toScalaWindowList(javaObj.download),
    toScalaWindowList(javaObj.advertisement),
    toScalaWindowList(javaObj.preorderExclusive),
    javaObj.playTypeIds.asScala.mapValues(toScalaWindowList).toMap
  )
}

val parsedJavaData: RDD[(String, Int, Int, Int, Int, String, GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows)] = mappingFile.map(x => {
   // your code producing the tuple
})

// convert to Scala objects and into a Row:
val inputData = parsedJavaData.map{
  case (id, jazzCount, rockCount, classicCount, nonclassicCount, musicType, javaPlayType) =>
    val scalaPlayType = toScalaGlobalizedWindows(javaPlayType)
    Row(id, jazzCount, rockCount, classicCount, nonclassicCount, musicType, scalaPlayType)
}

// now - this works
val inputDataDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(inputData, schema)
```

Comment: Thank You much for the brief explanation.