# SPARK : OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, emr

I am running a spark job on a EMR Cluster (A master with 10 slaves) of type r3.8xLarge:

```
spark.driver.cores   30
spark.driver.memory  200g
spark.executor.cores        16
spark.executor.instances    40
spark.executor.memory       60g 
spark.storage.memoryFraction   0.95
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions   2400
spark.default.parallelism  2400

spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
```

I keep getting this error :

```
16/10/11 07:02:46 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_8_piece0 on ip-172-31-10-29.ec2.internal:55123 in memory (size: 1721.0 B, free: 56.1 GB)
16/10/11 07:02:46 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 11
16/10/11 07:05:03 INFO SchedulerFactory: Job remoteInterpretJob_1476169306015 finished by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter1332927644
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
        at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:300)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344)
        at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:906)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.writeString(TBinaryProtocol.java:172)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterResult$RemoteInterpreterResultStandardScheme.write(RemoteInterpreterResult.java:743)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterResult$RemoteInterpreterResultStandardScheme.write(RemoteInterpreterResult.java:664)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterResult.write(RemoteInterpreterResult.java:586)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$interpret_result$interpret_resultStandardScheme.write(RemoteInterpreterService.java:4877)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$interpret_result$interpret_resultStandardScheme.write(RemoteInterpreterService.java:4839)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$interpret_result.write(RemoteInterpreterService.java:4790)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:53)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
(END)
```

Can some one tell me what should I do to avoid this error ?

Relevant Code (broad cast map):

I am creating a rdd of map with String key and CountryInfo(a Java POJO) as Value

```
val input = sc.textFile("s3:.....")

val metaData = input.map(x=> {
     val countryInfo = MappingUtils.getCountryInfo(x)   //converts string to POJO 

    val id = countryInfo.getId()

  (id, countryInfo)

  }).collectAsMap

val  broadcastedMap = sc.broadcast(metaData)
```

I have a data frame df = [itemId, id , timeStamp, itemCount]

Now I am trying to create a final dataframe based on df and the broadcastedMap with custom udfs :

```
  val result = df.withColumn("jazzCount",isJazz($"id") )
    .withColumn("rockCount",isRock($"id", $"tv"))
    .withColumn("classicCount",isClassic($"id"))
    .withColumn("nonclassicCount",isNonclassic($"id", $"kids"))
    .withColumn("musicType",getalbumType($"id"))
    .withColumn("playType",getTitleType($"id", $"eventTimestamp"))
```

Tried to create a data frame to avoid the broadcast so that I can do the join on df but getting error :

StructType I created :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

  val PlayTimeWindow =
    StructType(
      StructField("startTime", DateType, true) ::
        StructField("endTime", DateType, true) :: Nil)


  val globalizedPlayTimeWindows =
    StructType(
                StructField( "countries", ArrayType(StringType, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "purchase", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "rental", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "free", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "download", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "advertisement", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "playTypeIds", ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true )  ::
        StructField( "benefitIds", MapType(StringType, ArrayType(PlayTimeWindow, true), true), true)  :: Nil)



  val schema =    StructType(
     StructField("id", StringType, true) ::
      StructField("jazzCount", IntegerType, true) ::
      StructField("rockCount", IntegerType, true) ::
      StructField("classicCount", IntegerType, true) ::
      StructField("nonclassicCount", IntegerType, true) ::
      StructField("musicType", StringType, true) ::
      StructField( "playType", ArrayType(globalizedPlayTimeWindows, true), true) :: Nil)
```

Data frame creation :

```
val mappingFile = sc.textFile("s3://input.....")

val inputData = mappingFile.map(x=> {
    val countryInfo = MappingUtils.getCountryInfo(x)

    val id = countryInfo.getId

    val musicType = if(countryInfo.getmusicType != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(countryInfo.getmusicType)) countryInfo.getmusicType else "UNKOWN_TYPE"


    val classicWestern = if (countryInfo.getClassic() != null && countryInfo.getClassic.size() > 0) true  else false

    var nonclassicCount : Int = 0
    var  classicCount : Int = 0

    if (classicWestern) {
      classicCount = 1
    } else {
      nonclassicCount = 1
    }


    val jazzrock = if (countryInfo.getmusicType() != null && countryInfo.getmusicType != "JAZZ") true  else false
    var jazzCount : Int = 0
    var  rockCount : Int = 0

    if (jazzrock) {
      jazzCount = 1
    } else {
      rockCount = 1
    }

    val playType = if(countryInfo.getPlayTimeWindows != null && countryInfo.getPlayTimeWindows.size > 0 ) { countryInfo.getPlayTimeWindows.asScala.toList } else null

  (id, jazzCount, rockCount, classicCount, nonclassicCount, musicType ,playType)
  }).map{case (id, jazzCount, rockCount, classicCount, nonclassicCount, musicType,playType) => Row(id, jazzCount, rockCount, classicCount, nonclassicCount, musicType,playType)
  }.persist(DISK_ONLY)

 val inputDataDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(inputData, schema)
```

Struct's equivalent POJO :

```
@Data
public GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows(

    private final List<String> countries;

    private final List<PlayTimeWindow> purchase;

    private final List<PlayTimeWindow> rental;

    private final List<PlayTimeWindow> free;

    private final List<PlayTimeWindow> download;

    private final List<PlayTimeWindow> advertisement;

    private final List<PlayTimeWindow> preorderExclusive;

    private final Map<String, List<PlayTimeWindow>> playTypeIds;

}

@Data
public class PlayTimeWindow {

    private final Date startTime;

    private final Date endTime;
}
```

The error I am getting :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 12.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 12.0 (TID 393, ip-172-31-14-43.ec2.internal): scala.MatchError: GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows(countries=[US], purchase=null, rental=null, free=null, download=null, advertisement=null, preorderExclusive=null, playTypeIds=null) (of class com.model.global.GlobalizedPlayTimeWindows) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:255) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter$$anonfun$toCatalystImpl$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:163) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244) at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:163) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:153) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:260) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401) at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492) at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312) at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157) at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157) at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252) at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Driver stacktrace: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418) at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799) at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588) at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1538) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1538) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2125) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1537) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1544) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1414) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1413) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2138) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1413) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1495) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:171) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:394) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:355) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:363) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:163) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:168) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:170) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:172) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:174) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:176) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$$$c57ec8bf9b0d5f6161b97741d596ff0$$$$wC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:178) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:180) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:182) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:184) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:186) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:188) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:190) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:192) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:194) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:196) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:198) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:200) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:202) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:204) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:206) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:208) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:210) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:212) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:214) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:216) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:218) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:220) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:222) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:224) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:226) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:228) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:230) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:232) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:234) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:236) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:238) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:240) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:242) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:244) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:246) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:248) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:250) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:252) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:254) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:256) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:258) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:260) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:262) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:264) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:266) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:268) at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:270) at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:272) at $iwC.<init>(<console>:274) at <init>(<console>:276) at .<init>(<console>:280) at .<clinit>(<console>) at .<init>(<console>:7) at .<clinit>(<console>) at $print(<console>) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065) at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346) at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840) at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871) at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819) at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:664) at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:629) at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:622) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:57) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:276) at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:170) at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:118) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: show the relevant code: what transformations are you performing? The exception means some code is trying to create a very large array. This can happen, for instance, if you attempt to call `toArray` on a very large (but mostly empty) `SparseVector`.

Comment: @TzachZohar Updated the question. I believe the broadcasted map is huge. Is there any way I could avoid this ? I tried creating a StructType instead of broadcasted map but even that gives me error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970360/how-to-resolve-scala-matcherror-when-creating-a-data-frame

Comment: Consider using `join` instead of collecting and broadcasting a map (which would be very slow even if it would work, as it would have to serialize and send all the data over the network to and from your driver application). Join each record in `df1` with the relevant record(s) in `metaData` and use the relevant columns in your UDFs

Comment: @TzachZohar I initially wanted to create a data frame with relevant records from metaData but I couldn't create the case class with custom Type so I created a Struct type and used the schema to create data frame but I kept getting scala.MatchError when creating a Data Frame which I couldn't resolve yet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970360/how-to-resolve-scala-matcherror-when-creating-a-data-frame

Comment: If `metaData` is too large - broadcasting it is not a proper workaround...

Comment: @TzachZohar Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: As I wrote - using a `join` is usually the proper (and only) valid method for combining information from two large data sets.