# Is there any way that I can use scala type in java code so that I can convert my complex object to dataframe?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Right now, I have a list of complex objects in my java code. And when I try to use it to create a Dataframe, I got a MatchError. The code is somehow as below:

```
List<MyComplexPojo> myPojoList = new ArrayList<>();
for (....) {
    myPojoList.addAll( getAllValidPojos(...) );
}
DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myPojoList, MyComplexPojo.class); // throw MatchError
```

I googled it and it seems in java program, I cannot simply convert a complex java pojo to a Dataframe. However, I also found this [How to resolve scala.MatchError when creating a Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970360/how-to-resolve-scala-matcherror-when-creating-a-data-frame). According to it, if I use scala type instead of java type, I should be able to createDateFrame from it. For instance, I can use scala collection instead of java.util.List.

- Is that true that I have no way to convert a list of complex type java objects to data frame?
- If yes, then do I understand the url above correctly? More specifically, if I use scala type instead java type, am I able to create a Dataframe there?
- Is there any example of how to use scala type in java?
- If I can use scala type in java, how can I set the value of the object field in java code? Again, any example will be great. How can I add an element to a scala collection in java?

Comment: It would be nice if the code snippet were reproducible.